# Can i convert JSONResult to IEnumerable list in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jsonresult

I have a function that send a JSONResult, Now i want to use that function in C# and convert  that JSONResult to IEnumerable so i can iterate on that result and pass that data to a SelectList function. Can i do this and how? Im using Asp.Net MVC, JQuery and C#

Comment: does your JsonResult come from a business object? if yes you can just convert it the other way around

Comment: public JsonResult GetPostTypeChild(string data){ } How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not:

```
public myObject GetMyObject()
{
    myRepository db = new myRepository();
    return db.ListAllStuff();
}

public JsonResult GetMyJSON()
{
    return Json(GetMyObject(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public List<SelectList> GetMyEnumerable()
{
    return this.GetMyObject().ToList();
}
```

and you are reusing everything.

Answer (score 0):

Also it can be done in this way.

```
var data = GetJsonResultData(); //call to JsonResult method.

var datastr = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data.Data); // convert json object to string.

var dataclass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<modeldto>>(datastr ); // string json data to class list
```